# Reducing Flash file size in KB?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I have a Flash file that I need to reduce the size of.

The reason that I need to reduce its size is that I will need to convert this into an iPhone app.

currently it only has 2 buttons and 2 TLF textfileds on the stage one, layer one and the size of the file is 355KB.

I have also placed the code on layer 2.

is there anyway to reduce the size of it so I won't have problems when publishing and sending for app store?

Thanks

Comment: TLF is about 180kb of your total.  If you don't really need it and can use classic text, that will cut your size by 40%,  plus TLF runs poorly on most mobile devices anyway.

Comment: I thought about that. I need to use dynamic textfields to be honest but when I used dynamic textfields in the AIR for ios application in the flash, it doesn't work for some reason! but when I used TLF texts it will work but increases the file size! so its like catch 22... do you know why the dynamic textfiled doesn't work in Air for ios in flash cs6?

Comment: Are your buttons vector or are you using any bitmaps in your project?  Vector graphics (if not too complex) will take only a couple kb.   Can't help any further without seeing your project source.

Comment: the Classic textfields doesn't work either. it only shows "ex" in the classic textfield!!

Comment: I can tell you that dynamic text fields with classic text does work (as I've done before),  make sure your fonts are embedded and set to correct type (DF3)

Comment: @LondonDrugs_MediaServices, the buttons are Vector. I've changed the TLF texts to classic and it did reduce the file size alot. it is now 6kb BUT the classic textfileds do not show the texts that I want. infact in one of them only shows these two letters "ex". any suggestions?

Comment: If you're using FlashPRO,   in the library panel, right-click and choose `new font`,  select the font you wish to use and check the boxes next to the different character sets you'll need. Then click on the ActionScript tab and check "Export for ActionScript"

Comment: @DavidSmith haven't done much flash ios dev but I'm hoping you can use the Generate Size Report publish option and check exactly what takes up most space within resources. Although vectors are smaller, I'm not sure how well bitmap caching works on ios. If you're using bitmaps I recommend using texture atlases which you can easily generate with a tool like [TexturePacker](http://texturepacker.com)

Comment: right, I found out what the problem was. I needed to include all the characters for the embedded font as well... this is strange but now it works... Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The biggest portion of that file size will be related to TLF.   TLF (Text-Layout-Framework) is huge and is generally not recommended on mobile (as it has pretty high cpu usage).

If you're not using any TLF specific features, then it would be wise to change your text fields to use classic text instead (DF3).

Beyond TLF,  make sure you're using vector objects instead of bitmaps wherever you can as that will drastically reduce file size.   If you are using bitmaps, you can play around with the compression settings to optimize file size further.  You can do this globally in the Publish Settings  (JPEG Quality) or individually on a graphics properties menu.

One note with Vector graphics and mobile, simple vectors will run ok, but complex vectors will run terribly.  Make sure to set `cacheAsBitmap = true;` on any complex (or even all) vectors to improve performance.  OR in FLashPRO,  click on a movieClip and in the properties panel, go to the "Display" twirl down, and set cache as bitmap in the Render setting.    [image: Cache as Bitmap]

Comment: I've managed to reduce the size to 12KB which is not bad for now... I think I can reduce it a bit further by following your suggestions and others. Thank you very much.